# iOS - Create iOS9-like split view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit

I want to make something like iOS9 split view in my app. 
If you are not familiar with what I'm talking about here is what it looks like:
[image]
Basically I want a ability to finger-adjust the width of two view-controllers. Is there any drop-in solutions for that? If not, how do I implement thing like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place a UIView with custom appearance in the middle of two view controllers and handle pan gesture recongnizer for that like so:

```
func handleMiddleViewPanGesture(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gestureRecognizer.state {
    case .Began:
        startingMiddlePanRect = middleView.frame
    case .Changed:
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translationInView(middleView)
        middleView.frame.origin.x = startingMiddlePanRect.origin.x + translation.x
        updateFrames()
    default:
        ///...
    }

}
```